# What is a "server application"?

Tags: web-applications

What exactly is a "server application"? I've been asked to write an essay about bugs in "server applications" and I'm unfamiliar with the exact term. Are they just web-applications, or are they something else?

Answer (score 3):

[image]

**1. What is a client-server application?**

Client-server describes an application architecture in which the client requests an action or service from the provider of service, the server. Consider a Web browser and a Web server. When you address a URL in the browser window, it (client) requests a page from a Web server. The server returns an html page to the client, which parses the page (data) and displays it on your computer.

When developing a client-server application, like the Web browser and Web server, you need to consider how you are going to handle developing your application in a team environment and how you are going to handle long-term maintenance. Developing client-server applications parallels developing modular programs. Modular programming separates large applications into smaller constituent pieces to ease development in teams and provide better maintainability. In a client-server application, a module does not have to be part of the same program or even run on the same computer. Each modular function can run on a different device.

**2. How does a client perform?**

Client programs request service from a server by sending it a message. Referring back to the Web example, a Web browser is a client we use everyday to request Web pages. For example, when you clicked the link to read this article, your browser sent a message to a Web server in Austin, TX. In response, your browser received the html page you are now reading. A Web browser represents many client programs, which manage the graphical user interface (GUI) or display portion of an application; determining the presentation of the service provided by an application.

**3. What is a server's function?**

Server programs process client requests by performing the tasks requested by clients. For example, in a Web browser the Web server returns the html page requested by the client. But client requests and server programs are not always so simple. Consider a more complicated application in which you buy a product on a Web page. In this case, the client informs the server what you are purchasing and the server updates a database with the purchase request. Then, the server informs the client that the order has been placed.

Servers are generally passive as they wait for a client request. During these waiting periods servers can perform other tasks or perform maintenance. Unlike the client, the server must continually run because clients can request service at any time. Clients on the other hand only need to run when they require service. Many server applications allow for multiple clients to request service. For example, while you are reading this page others interested in client-server programming could also request and read the same Web page.

Original Article is **[here](http://www.ni.com/white-paper/4431/en/)**

Also take a look at this article

**[An Empirical Study of Reported Bugs in Server Software with Implications for Automated Bug Diagnosis](https://www.ideals.illinois.edu/bitstream/handle/2142/13697/TR-ServerReliability.pdf?sequence=6)**

Answer (score 2):

A "server application" is an application that waits for requests from other applications and responds to them, thus providing a "service" upon their request. A web server is a server application.

Answer (score 0):

A "server application" binds to a [well-known port](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers#Well-known_ports) and has a reachable address (and OPTIONALLY a name). For example, the web server for Google listens on `port 80` (HTTP) and has (many) address(es) that resolve from "www.google.com". In this case, we are talking about a "web server application". Other "server applications" would run the gamut of the "well-known" port(s) and venture into obscurity with proprietary applications and protocols.

In contrast a "client application" depends (to some or less) extent on a "server". Some protocols are decentralized, for example `git` or `bittorent`. In contrast, Microsoft Outlook (or any other e-mail client) cannot send mail without Microsoft Exchange (or any other mail server).